# Type [undefined, undefined] | [number, number] is not assignable to type [number, number]

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is all using TypeScript.

I have a function called 'extent' from an external library that returns either [number, number] or [undefined, undefined], so I can't change this function itself.

I have a function called 'getMaxRange', and it takes in an array of numbers, and returns an array of length 2, each containing a number, as such: [number, number]

If I type something like

```
getMaxRange = (points: number[]) : [number, number] => {
    const range = extent(points));
    if (range == [undefined, undefined]) {
        return [0,1];
    }
    else{
        return range;
    }

}
```

it gives an error that `Type [undefined, undefined] | [number, number] is not assignable to type [number, number]`.

What is the best approach to make it so I don't get this error? How can I get it to know that range cannot be [undefined, undefined] anymore?

Answer (score 1):

`if (range == [undefined, undefined])` is always `false`. Using `==` or `===` to compare arrays checks to see if they're the **same** array, not if they have the same contents.

You'd need to check the array elements:

```
if (range[0] === undefined && range[1] === undefined)
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB5WWKAKADnGLAZwC5EwQBbAI2QCcBtAXQEoyGKb6Aacq2uk0QAfRA3AATZMELIJvSdNkShAbwBQiLYjrIoIOkgCyAQygALAHR0TYCXErYWiADyIADJYCsiAPxiARl4AJiF2RRkwOQU7JSiVAG51AF91dQgEIihEAHM9U1QAJVs8xABeRDwCYjJOAWZndjqePi5BcoA%20RA1tRAywLJ0S5HKUdEwcfEIoIhYk3phgSpswPIZ3ITKtxAjlRAAyfaHV5AYAze3d%20Oce3u1dfUMxd25z%20e1U3uQAGyJkW7uOj0BiQKzy7y0qWSCSAA)

Actually, given the types, just checking one element is sufficient:

```
if (range[0] === undefined)
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB5WWKAKADnGLAZwC5EwQBbAI2QCcBtAXQEoyGKb6Aacq2uk0QAfRA3AATZMELIJvSdNkShAbwBQiLYjrIoIOkgCyAQygALAHR0TYCXErYWiADyIADJYCsiAPxiARl4AJiF2RRkwOQU7JSiVAG51AF91dQgEIihEAHM9U1QAJVs8xABeRDwCYjJOAWZndjqePi5BcoA%20RA1tRAywLJ0S5HKUdEwcfEIoIhYk3phgSpswPIZ3ITKtxAjlZx7e7V19QzF3bgCmee1U3uQAGyJkA8OdPQMkFbzrrVTkhKAA)

In runtime terms, this would also work:

```
if (range.includes(undefined))
```

but with that TypeScript doesn't recognize the guard and you'd have to mark it explicitly with an assertion, so probably better to use the first version.

Comment: ah yeah that would do it, completely passed over my head

Comment: @AndrewZaw - :-) Glad that helped!

Comment: @AndrewZaw - I just realized that given the types, you only really need to check one element. Updated the answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can check array elements

```
getMaxRange = (points: number[]) : [number, number] => {
    const range = extent(points));
    if (range[0] === undefined || range[1] === undefined) {
        return [0,1];
    }
    else{
        return range;
    }

}
```